# Tricentis Tosca - How can i able to send this key combination? FN+SHIFT+F12

Tags: automation, tosca

Tricentis Tosca - How can i able to send this key combination? FN+SHIFT+F12

Have tried with {KEYPRESS[SHIFT]}{KEYPRESS[FN]}{KEYDOWN[F12]} but i get error "Sequence contains more than one element"

Anyone can share the solution? thanks

Comment: you use KEYPRESS and KEYDOWN wrong way round. KEYPRESS presses and releases the key while yoou dont want to release SHIFT and FN before you press F12.